# Unable to transfer DAI token to Smart Contract on Ropsten Testnet using Metamask and Remix

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, metamask, remix, erc20

The code below mentioned has the two methods which I'm trying to use to transfer DAI tokens (0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D) from my Metamask wallet to the Smart Contract.

In Method - 1: Some unnamed token is getting transferred but no DAI transfer (what is that unnamed token denoted by () why is it getting created?) .. the code is running fine and no errors are being thrown in this case.

In Method - 2: A gas estimation error is being thrown when I'm trying to use transferFrom to send DAI from my address to the Smart Contract.

Need a correction or alternative way to send DAI or any other token for that matter, please.

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 // DAI - 0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D

 import "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";   

contract DAI_txn {

    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    IERC20 public token;
    uint public amount;

constructor(
    address _token
) {
    token = IERC20(_token);
    amount = 10;
} 

function deposit_DAI() public returns(bool) {

    // address x = payable(msg.sender);
    bool success;

    // Method - 1: DAI is not being transferred, some un-named token is getting transferred
    // (success, ) = payable(x).call(abi.encodePacked("token.transfer(address, uint256)", address(this), amount));

    // Method - 2:Commented part throwing gas estimation error on remix
    token.approve(address(this), amount * 2);
    success = token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

    return success;
} 

function balance() public view returns (uint) {
    return token.balanceOf(address(this));
}
```

}

Comment: Solution number 2 seems right, but why not use an address instead of a payable(address)!?

Comment: It's still throwing this **error** - Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted - @HosseinAsadi

Comment: Tried this as well showing (_approve - Undeclared Identifier) although I imported --import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

        `// Method -3:   _approve(x, address(this), token, amount);   token.transferFrom(x, address(this), amount);`